# How to determine the value of Android MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE

Tags: android, audio, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to encode

Audio data:

- Sample rate = 44100 Hz
- Monoral Channel
- PCM_16BIT

to some AAC by `MediaCodec`

The codec configuration is a bit confusing, but so far I did as follows at least with no error.

```
    codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
    MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
    format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 1*44100*16);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectHE);
    codec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
```

Here's only my guess so if you find it wrong please tell me so.

`KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT` = 1 corresponds to the audio source attribute: `Monoral Channel = 1`,

`KEY_SAMPLE_RATE` = 44100 to the audio source attribute: `Sample rate = 44100 Hz`,

and since the audio source attribute is PCM_16BIT, `KEY_BIT_RATE` should be  `1*44100*16`.

Am I correct? I try to find documentation, but could not find on the web. Thanks.

Comment: For the encoders, `KEY_BIT_RATE` refers to the desired *output* bit rate, not the *input* bit rate.  The official doc is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html , but the descriptions are a bit terse.

Comment: Thank you, you should move your comment to the answer section, so I could check your comment as the answer.

Comment: fadden, Do you know some good resource for encoding to AAC by `MediaCodec` ? The only sample code I could find so far is https://gist.github.com/wobbals/3990442 , and I have no idea how to pull the output stream from this class, so.

Comment: Moved to answer section.  I added a link to the bigflake site, which is mostly related to video encoding, but the EncoderTest does exercise the audio codecs.  Unfortunately I haven't worked with audio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the encoders, `KEY_BIT_RATE` refers to the desired *output* bit rate, not the *input* bit rate. The official doc is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html), but the descriptions are a bit terse.

The CTS [EncoderTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncoderTest) encodes audio.  It's not much to go on, but it has the basic elements.

Comment: Thanks, in fact, I have seen this page before, and I should investigate more. Perhaps, I may have some question later, and hopefully you  give me a suggestion on that.